# integration of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^2}{(z-3)(z^n-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Integration of

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^2}{(z-3)(z^n-1)}$$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 5$

**Solution i tried**- Here the singualrities of given function is in  are all in $|z|\leq1$ and here $z=3$ is not a singularity so we have to integrate with $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{z^2}{(z-3)}$. here i am not getting how to think about singularities in $(z^n-1)$

please help

Tahnk you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First of all $z=3$ is a singularity. And in fact the most important in this problem.

Instead of computing the residues inside the circle, compute them outside of it. It is much simpler!

> You will obtain:$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^2 dz}{(z-3)(z^n-1)}=-\operatorname{Res}_{z=3}f(z)-\underbrace{\operatorname{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z)}_{=0}=-\frac{3^2}{3^n-1}.$$

Comment: Out the counter, never heard about this.

Comment: @TheStudent What do you mean by "the counter"?

Comment: sorry this is contour

Comment: @thestudent It is a very simple concept. If a function is one-valued and has finite number of singularities, the sum over all residues including that at infinity is zero.

Comment: Now i got this ,+1 for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let  g(z) be the integrand. We know

$$\tag 1\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}g(z)\,dz = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \text {Res }(g,z_k),$$

where $z_1,\dots ,z_n$ are the $n$ roots of unity.

Let $R>3.$ We can also say

$$\tag 2 \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}g(z)\,dz = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \text {Res }(g,z_k)+ \text {Res }(g,3).$$

Exercise: Using basic estimates on the size of a contour integral, show that the left side of $(2)$ tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty.$ (This holds if $n\ge 3$; I don't know why they write $n\ge 5.$) Since the left side of $(2)$ is constant, it must be $0.$ It follows that $(1)=-\text {Res }(g,3).$

Comment: Can we extend counter? Here in question counter is $|z|\leq 2$ then how can we write it $|z|\leq R$.